# how to compare 2 columns and if the value in A is higher than B, copy the value of A over B

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, conditional-formatting, spreadsheet

I'm trying to compare 2 columns of similar data and would appriciate some help. i need to know how to do the following. I what to know how to compare the values in column A with column B, then if the values in column A are greater than B. then copy the value of A over the value of B.

If someone could let me know the easiest way to do this it would be appriciated

Comment: Only VBA macro can solve this task inplace. But you may create a formula  in column С: `C1 =MAX(A1,B1)`, drag it down (it will be filled automatically), copy column C, paste special to column B with "values only", then clear or remove column C.

Comment: Thanks mate i'll give that a go and get back to you cheer